# Listar carpetas y archivos en Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

Quiero realizar un programa que me diga que carpetas y archivos tengo dentro de una ruta dada. El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>

int main(){
     QStringList lista = QDir("C:/Imagenes").entryList();
     qDebug() << lista;
     return 0;
}
```

La carpeta "Imagenes" contiene dos imágenes y una carpeta como se puede ver en la imagen siguiente:

[image: Carpeta "Imagenes"]

Al ejecutar el programa, obtengo com salida lo siguiente:

[image: Salida programa]

Mi pregunta es por qué se obtiene como salida "." y ".." además de los archivos y carpetas que hay en el directorio y como podría conseguir solo listar las dos imágenes y la carpeta "Nuevas".

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posible solución: usando otro de los constructores proporcionados por `QDir`:

```
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>

int main(){
  QStringList lista = QDir("C:/Imagenes", QString( ), SortFlags( Name | IgnoreCase ), Filters( NoDotAndDotDot ) ).entryList();
  qDebug() << lista;
  return 0;
}
```

Como ves, el único cambio son los argumentos *extra* pasados al constructor. `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` sirve para hacer precisamente lo que pides: **excluir** las entradas especiales `.` y `..`.

<sub>Mas información sobre el constructor [aquí](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#QDir-3)</sub>

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente utilizando filtros. Saludos!